# Should I avoid multiple onresize listener?

Tags: javascript, performance, events

Is it considered bad practice to have multiple "onresize" javascript event listeners in a single page?

My script currently looks something like that:

```
(...)

callFuntion1();
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
    callFuntion1();
}, 300));
(...)

callFuntion2();
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
    callFuntion2();
}, 300));
(...)

if(something){
    callFuntion3();
    $(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
        callFuntion3();
    }, 300));
}
(...)
```

Should I find a way to factorize the onresize listeners? Can multiple listeners have an impact on a website's performance?

Comment: Oh yes, please avoid it!

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: You should bind only one resize listener with all the logic inside. It's better from support point of view and from performance point too. Your current version looks weird.

Comment: @DmitryVolokh What about listeners scattered on multiple js files? Should it be better to bind them all?

Comment: @sawsan Guess, you should think about your app design, cause the way when you need multiple listeners for resize event is a sign that smth. went wrong during design/development. Probably, pub/sub pattern usage suits for your app. But it's difficult to give advices without seeing the code.

Comment: @DmitryVolokh I was mainly asking for a general advice to help building a responsive web app, so no code to show. But I get the point, thanks.

Comment: If you're worried about performance issues than you should switch to vanilla JS.